# Who is the person behind the so-called "Boure's Law"?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, terminology, soft-question, rigid-body-dynamics

When I was in college, specifically in Rigid Body Kinematics, I was taught that *Boure's law* or *formula*, which looks something along these lines: $$\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\mathrm{d} t}\right)_{\text{fixed}}=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\mathrm{d} t}\right)_{\text{moving}}+\boldsymbol{\Omega}\times\boldsymbol{\omega}$$ which is pretty standard, and I'm sure it appears in most syllabi. It provides a way to calculate the derivative (in this case, the time derivative) of a vector respect the absolute frame of reference, given the derivative with respect to a moving inertial frame. Another similar example can be seen in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535962/derivative-of-angular-momentum-in-a-rotating-frame-of-reference).

My question is however who is Boure? Is it Bouré instead? Who used it for the first time instead of the more widespread *total* or *absolute derivative*, and when? Years later I only get a few results for this obscure naming. If I've tagged this question incorrectly or this is not the place to ask this, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Which college textbook?

Comment: It isn’t called that my country. Google seems to know nothing about “Boure’s law”, “Boure’s formula”, “Bouré’s law”, or “Bouré’s formula” so “obscure naming” is a good description. My guess is that this person is from whatever country the textbook author is from. I would have thought Euler found this formula, so it might be a French vs. German attribution issue. Of course, many formulas are found multiple times by multiple people, working independently without knowledge of the others.

Comment: Hi, perhaps your question is more suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a case where a formula is named in one country, and those influenced by it, because a discoverer was from that country. However, other countries don't deem the formula significant enough to merit being named.

In this case, the above formula was discovered by the Frenchman [Edmond Bour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmond_Bour), and is known as the [Bour formula](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_des_mouvements#Pr%C3%A9ambule_:_formule_de_Bour). Notably, the Wikipedia page that formula appears on is only available in French.

The formula is also named in Spanish, however the surname is spelled Boure not Bour (see e.g. [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/85003526.pdf) and [here](https://issuu.com/secsa/docs/mec_nica_ii_08_movimiento_relativo)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nick. You extinguished a long-time question of mine. Maybe the change from Bour to *Boure was a typo that passed down from books to teachers to students, etc.; or a way to make it sound more French?